# How do I get a SAA7231 TV Tuner card working?

Tags: tv-tuner

I have recently bought a new pc and installed Ubuntu (as you do) all works well but my tv tuner isn't being detected.

The model is a SAA7231, can someone please help me install it.  What steps do I need to take firstly to give you all the correct info?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bunch of DVB cards you usually need to install the firmware and then a TV application like TVtime:

- [linux-firmware-nonfree](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/linux-firmware-nonfree) [image: Install linux-firmware-nonfree]
- [tvtime](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tvtime) [image: Install tvtime]

Unfortunately this is the best source for [a driver](http://www.jusst.de/hg/saa7231/) that I could find, which appears unmaintained. Looks like some guys tried to get it [working in SUSE](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/450034-saa7231-module.html) but also it didn't look good.

Comment: I have winfast TV tuner, tvtime didn't help, can you suggest some driver? Thanks.

Comment: @umprirsky It's probably best to ask a separate question for that card.

Comment: That driver is a 404 now.